# Custom form region in Outlook - certain buttons are disabled

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook

I've built a custom mail Outlook form (Outlook 2007) and want the user to be
able to attach an email or file to the form before sending. The Insert File
icon is available on the toolbar when sending a standard new mail form, but
is disabled in the custom mail form. I can't find any properties or controls in
design mode that will add the functionality to the custom form.

The form currently does all I need it to do except insert file and a few other functions such as text editing (same issue - the buttons are disabled).

How do I enabled these buttons in my custom form?

Answer (score 0):

I still can't get these buttons enabled. From everything I'm reading and seeing with Outlook's form designer (I'm developing in Visual Studio using C# btw) the problem is related to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._DocSiteControl.

This is the message body control. It has a property SuppressAttachments. I created a class that extends Window's RichTextBox and implements DocSiteControl and then set SuppressAttachments = 0 in its initialization but still no go.

```
public class MyTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._DocSiteControl
{
    private sbyte _suppressAttachements;
    private sbyte _readOnly;
    public sbyte ReadOnly
    {
        get { return _readOnly; }
        set { _readOnly = value; }
    }

    public sbyte SuppressAttachments
    {
        get { return _suppressAttachements; }
        set { _suppressAttachements = value; }
    }
}
```